# plot() function 'col=' argument does not work when rows shuffled in 'data='

Tags: r

I'm just noticing a rather strange phenomenon with the plot() function for making scatterplots via the formula notation.

Comparing the following two commands:

```
plot(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, data=iris, col=Species)
plot(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, data=iris[sample(1:nrow(iris)),], col=Species)
```

I would expect the same plot since the second command simply shuffles up the rows prior to plotting. However, we see that the colors of the points are shuffled as well in the second line. Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that when you sample the data within the `plot` statement it's setting the color mapping according to `iris$Species` but the data that mapping is applied to is the reordered data frame.

```
head(iris)
```

> ```
>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
> ```

```
head(iris[sample(1:nrow(iris)),])
```

> ```
>     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
> 103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 virginica
> 12           4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2    setosa
> 128          6.1         3.0          4.9         1.8 virginica
> 145          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5 virginica
> 42           4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3    setosa
> 41           5.0         3.5          1.3         0.3    setosa
> ```

A more explicit mapping with the sampling moved safely outside of `plot()`:

```
plot(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, data=iris, col=c("red","blue","green")[iris$Species])

df1 <- iris[sample(1:nrow(iris)),]
plot(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, data=df1, col=c("red","blue","green")[df1$Species])
```

Where

```
 c("red","blue","green")[iris$Species]
```

> [1] "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red" 
>   "red"
>        [18] "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red" 
>   "red"
>        [35] "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   "red" 
>   "blue" 
>        [52] "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"
>   "blue" 
>        [69] "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"
>   "blue" 
>        [86] "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue" 
>   "green" "green"
>       [103] "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green"
>   "green" "green"
>       [120] "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green"
>   "green" "green"
>       [137] "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green"

and

```
c("red","blue","green")[df1$Species]
```

> [1] "blue"  "green" "red"   "blue"  "green" "blue"  "green" "red"
>   "green" "blue"  "blue"  "green" "red"   "green" "blue"  "blue"  "red" 
>   [18] "red"   "blue"  "blue"  "green" "red"   "blue"  "green" "green"
>   "red"   "green" "blue"  "red"   "blue"  "green" "blue"  "green"
>   "green"  [35] "red"   "blue"  "red"   "red"   "blue"  "blue"  "blue" 
>   "blue"  "blue"  "red"   "green" "red"   "red"   "blue"  "red"   "red" 
>   "green"  [52] "blue"  "blue"  "green" "red"   "green" "blue"  "red"
>   "green" "red"   "red"   "red"   "blue"  "green" "green" "blue"  "red" 
>   "red"    [69] "green" "red"   "red"   "green" "blue"  "blue"  "green"
>   "red"   "red"   "green" "green" "green" "red"   "green" "red"   "red" 
>   "red"    [86] "red"   "blue"  "green" "green" "green" "green" "green"
>   "red"   "blue"  "green" "green" "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "red"
>   "green" "green" [103] "red"   "green" "blue"  "red"   "red"   "green"
>   "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "green" "green" "red"   "blue"  "blue"  "blue"
>   "blue"  "blue"  [120] "green" "green" "red"   "red"   "blue"  "red"
>   "blue"  "blue"  "green" "red"   "blue"  "green" "blue"  "red"   "blue"
>   "green" "red"   [137] "green" "green" "green" "green" "blue"  "red"
>   "red"   "blue"  "green" "red"   "red"   "blue"  "red"   "red"

Resulting in identical plots.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I know that this workaround does the trick, but it seems surprising that the col= argument behaves in that way. My hunch is that it actually runs sample() again, separately from the sample() call that gives the x and y coordinates. Otherwise, I would expect something like plot(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, data=iris[-(2:9),], col=Species) to run into similar issues.

Comment: @east  Yes that is also what I was thinking. It would be easy to verify by walking through the source code of `plot()`. It's probably not a very good practice to sample within a function like that though, especially without setting a seed.